# Use Laravel "distinct" validation rule but ignore some array entries based on an array property

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5, distinct

I want to validate an array of input data using a Form Request in Laravel. 
The array looks like this:

```
[
  'issues' =>
  [
     'type' => 'prio_1',
     'note' => 'This is some text'
  ],
  [
     'type' => 'prio_2',
     'note' => 'This is some other text'
  ]
  [
     'type' => 'prio_1',
     'note' => 'This is yet some other text',
     'deleted' => true
  ]
]
```

I want to validate that the the `type` field is `distinct` in this array, taking into account that the third array entry is `deleted` and thus needs to be ignored for this rule.
Using

```
["issues.*.type" => 'required|distinct']
```

does not work of course as this rule cannot be parameterised to ignore the rule in case an array property has a certain value.
Filtering the input to leave out the deleted entries is not an option either, as the index replacing the `*` in the response needs to match the original index in the request.

Is there a way to extend the `distinct` rule (using a custom validator) to allow for this kind of validation? Or any other way to allow for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-closures) and a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) to check to see if there are duplicated (excluding "deleted" items):

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "issues.*.type" => [
            'required', function ($attr, $value, $fail) {
                $count = collect($this->input('issues'))
                    ->reject(function ($item) {
                        return isset($item['deleted']) && $item['deleted'];
                    })
                    ->filter(function ($item) use ($value) {
                        return $item['type'] === $value;
                    })
                    ->count();

                if ($count > 1) {
                    $fail(__('validation.distinct'));
                }
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

---

To make things more efficient you could also just count the values before and just check to see if the count is more than one:

```php
public function rules()
{
    $duplicateTypes = collect($this->input('issues'))
        ->reject(function ($item) {
            return isset($item['deleted']) && $item['deleted'];
        })
        ->groupBy('type')
        ->map->count();

    return [
        "issues.*.type" => [
            'required', function ($attr, $value, $fail) use($duplicateTypes) {
                if ($duplicateTypes[$value] > 1) {
                    $fail(__('validation.distinct'));
                }
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```